# Can I add padding to a QwtText object?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am adding a `QwtPlotMarker` to a `QwtPlot` using the following code:

```
QwtPlotMarker *tooltip = new QwtPlotMarker(tr("Tooltip"));

QwtText label("02/01/17\n06:00:00\nVoltage: 4.02");
QColor blue(QColor(30, 140, 220));
label.setColor(blue);
label.setBorderPen(QPen(blue, 1));
label.setBorderRadius(5);
label.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(65, 177, 225, 50));

QFont font("MS Shell Dlg 2", 8);
label.setFont(font);

tooltip->setLabel(label);
tooltip->setLabelAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignTop);    
tooltip->attach(this);

this->replot();
```

where `this` points to a `QwtPlot` object.

With the code above I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Note that in the image the letter `V` from the Voltage is overlapped by the border.

Is it possible to add padding to the `QwtText` (or maybe to the `QwtPlotMarker`!?), so I can get a result like the following one?

[image]

I'm using `Qt 5.3.2` and `Qwt 6.1.0`.

Comment: Unsure how many people know Qwt (neither do I) but the picture looks like Qt stylesheet was used. Try to obtain stylesheet via http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop and try to programmatically modify / set new one.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVX. I believe it uses style sheets but I have searched in the [Qwt Documenatation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html) and could not find any related style sheet function (e.g. `styleSheet` or `setStyleSheet`) for the `QwtPlot` and the `QwtPlotMarker`.

Comment: If Qwt is based on Qt then there is a good chance that those types are derived from QWidget? If so, the base has those methods. @KelvinS

Comment: I know `QwtPlot` is derived from `QFrame` (so it probably has the stylesheet methods) but I don't think `QwtText` is. I have also searched for some related function directly on Qt (using `Ctrl+Spacebar`) but found nothing.

Comment: KevinS, just try `qDebug() << objQwt->styleSheet();` and see.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, it returned the following error message: `'class QwtText' has no member named 'styleSheet'` and `'class QwtPlotMarker' has no member named 'styleSheet'`

Comment: Ok. Those are not widgets. Cannot tell you more. Or maybe some class member is the widget? That pic looks like the widget styled. I used to do that.